# Icons disappear and everything freezes

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (running on HP Spectre x360). Quite recently the following problem has occurred:

Every so often (maybe every 30 minutes at this point), the WiFi does, the bar that has all my icons disappears, and also the bar that has volume and WiFi and clock etc. also disappears.

Things also freeze and I have to hard restart.

I don't even know where to begin trying to fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

I upgraded to 18.04 and it was working fine for a while. But then this same thing happened.

---

Occassionally it will also fail to some kind of terminal screen with scrolling error messages:

[image: Error messages]

Comment: Please, check your harddrive with smartmontools, and make a backup. It is better to use magic request to shutdown the system in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely you have either a failing hard drive, a corrupted filesystem, or both.

### Backup before anything bad happens

I'd start by making backups of everything you *really* need. Start by just plugging in a USB drive and copying over any very important files you have that you can't afford to miss. Just drag your files onto a USB drive in Files.

Then, try copying your entire home directory to a safe place. Drop to a root shell and make a tarball.

```
$ sudo su -
# cd /home
# tar -cvpfz home-directory.tar.gz <your username>
# cp home-directory.tar.gz <somewhere safe, on another drive>
```

If you can, verify you can open that tarball on another machine and that it has all your files.

### Test and repair your disk

From there, [you can follow the official Ubuntu instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en) on checking your disc for problems.